# Modify this Python program to generate only the subsets with odd sums?

Tags: python, string, subset

I want it to take as input a set of numbers, such as [1,2,3,4], and only give the subsets with odd sums. For example, [1],[1,2],[2,3] etc.

I haven't tried much, I'm not sure where to start. Sorry, I'm very new to programming, but here's what I have so far. It generates all the possible subsets.

```
    def rsubsets(s):
        if len(s) == 0:
           return [[]]
        temp = rsubsets(s[1:])
        new = []
        for itm in temp:
           new.append(itm)
        n = len(new)
        for j in range(n):
           new[j] = new[j] + [s[0]]
        return temp + new
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not take the return value of all subsets that you've generated, and check for the ones that have an odd sum?

Comment: Just putting a question mark on the end of the title doesn't make it a question.

Answer (score 3):

Build upon your existing function:

```
def odd_subsets(s):
    return [x for x in rsubsets(s) if sum(s) % 2 == 1]
```

Or without the comprehension:

```
def odd_subsets(s):
    odd = []
    for subset in rsubsets(s):
        if sum(s) % 2 == 1:
            odd.append(subset)
    return odd
```

Comment: How would I put this in the same function?

Comment: @user1871071: Why do you want to?

Comment: My goal was to edit the original function to only output subsets with odd sums.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
def odd_subsets(s):
    lRet = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        lRet.extend([c for c in itertools.combinations(s,i+1) if sum(c)%2==1])
    return lRet
```

If you are dead set on using your initial function this is the easiest way to pull it off

```
def rsubsets(s):
    def all_subsets(s):
        if len(s) == 0:
           return [[]]
        temp = all_subsets(s[1:])
        new = []
        for itm in temp:
           new.append(itm)
        n = len(new)
        for j in range(n):
           new[j] = new[j] + [s[0]]
        return temp + new
    return [i for i in all_subsets(s) if sum(i)%2==1]
```

Pretty much what this does is call your initial recursive function and filter the results.

Another way is to use a flag...

```
def rsubsets(s,bFilter=True):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return [[]]
    temp = rsubsets(s[1:],False)
    new = []
    for itm in temp:
       new.append(itm)
    n = len(new)
    for j in range(n):
       new[j] = new[j] + [s[0]]
    if bFilter:
        return [i for i in temp+new if sum(i)%2 ==1]
    return temp + new
```